# How to add Compass in option menu for Google map in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, compass-geolocation

I have work for Google map . i want to add Compass in Google map , but in Option menu .

that means when i press the "menu" button then there will be option for Compass Mood On/Off.

How i can do that ?  Is there any tutorial or suggestion for this ?

please Help .

Comment: If you have got the ans please let us know

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [MyLocationOverlay](https://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html?com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) provided by the Google Map library. Especialy, have a look at methods:

```
public boolean isCompassEnabled();
public boolean enableCompass();
public void disableCompass();
```

For the menu, you can have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu (or search stackoverflow...)